# How to say throw away: 扔掉?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

CantoDict lists 扔掉 as the translation for "throw away" as in "throw away the can," but I often hear people use 扔 by itself or 掉 by itself.

1. Is 扔掉 the formal way of saying "throw away"?
2. Is there a difference between using 扔 or 掉?

Comment: see dictionaries: ＂汉语水平考试词典＂：扔［义２］丢掉；抛弃（throw away;cast aside):随地～垃圾要罚款的｜这些愉快的回忆早就～在脑后了。bkrs： 扔 。。。
（抛弃; 丢） throw away; cast aside:
把它扔了吧。 Throw it away.
不要在地板上乱扔纸屑。 Don't litter up the floor with scraps of paper.
那个疯子把自己的手表和皮夹子扔了。 The madman flung away his watch and his wallet.
我认为应该把它扔进历史的垃圾箱。 I think that should be relegated to the garbage can of history.
这事他早就扔在脖子后边了。 He'd clean forgotten about it.

Comment: I see that you tagged both "cantonese" and "mandarin". Is this question about Cantonese or Mandarin? Because the answer may be different for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is 扔掉 the formal way of saying "throw away"?

Yes, it is.

'掉' in  '扔掉' is a [result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complement), not a verb itself.

> 2) Is there a difference between using 扔 or 掉?

- 扔 mainly mean 'throw'
- 掉 mainly mean 'drop'

you can 扔 forward, backward, upward or downward; But you can only  掉 downward

Answer (score 1):

I'm a native Cantonese and I have always used 掉 to represent 'throw'

Comment: you meant you always use  掉 for 'throw away'. You can't serious think saying  '把球掉給我' instead of '  把球扔給我 ' is acceptable.

Comment: @TangHo we don't use 扔 or 給 in Cantonese, if not, quite rarely. Native Cantonese speakers use 俾 instead of 給

Comment: If you are talking about colloquial Cantonese, It is "將個波擲(or 掟)俾我" ;  " 把球扔給我 " is SWC (standard written Chinese that Cantonese use for writing) I am a native Cantonese speaker too. We can also say , "抛俾我"

Comment: BTW,   beside '掉垃圾' people also use  '抌垃圾' , '丟垃圾' or "擗垃圾"   for "throw away the garbage"

Comment: @Tang Ho wow I've never heard of 擗垃圾 before. and I never knew we would write in SWC in Mandarin instead of Cantonese. Why can't SWC be in Cantonese too? :( Thanks for the insight!